# pandas str.contains match against multiple strings and get the matched values

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, numpy

in the below example, i am able to match a pandas column containing text data against multiple collection of strings. The output will only tell me whether any part of the `df.col1` cell contains one of the elements from the collection. it will not tell me which one! I am interested in getting exactly that (the string matched or better still its positional location in the collection array)

```
words = ['dog', 'monkey']
pat = "|".join(map(re.escape, words))

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['lion bites dog','dog bites monkey','monkey bites man','man bites apple']})
df.loc[df.col1.str.contains(pat),'col1']
```

the reason why i need to know which string from the collection (words above) was matched is because each element of the collection could be mapped to a numeric value. like

```
words_dict = {'dog':'1', 'monkey':'2'}
```

i can perhaps try `df.map(dict)`but in the actual case, the collection is stored in a `pandas dataframe`

```
words_df = pd.DataFrame({1:['dog'], 2:['monkey']})
```

i can think of a rather circuitous solution of checking for each element in the collection iteratively but that seems to be highly inefficient, if the number of elements in the collection is large.

edit//

the desired output can be either:

```
[0,0,1,NaN] or ['dog','dog','monkey',False]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***concept 1***
using sets

```
s = df.col1.str.split().apply(set)

s - (s - set(words))

0            {dog}
1    {monkey, dog}
2         {monkey}
3               {}
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

***concept 2***
using `str.get_dummies`

```
df.col1.str.get_dummies(sep=' ')[words]

   dog  monkey
0    1       0
1    1       1
2    0       1
3    0       0
```

Stretching this to get desired results

```
d1 = df.col1.str.get_dummies(sep=' ')
d2 = d1.loc[:, d1.columns.intersection(words)]
d2[d2.any(1)].idxmax(1).reindex(d2.index)

0       dog
1       dog
2    monkey
3       NaN
dtype: object
```

***concept 3***
using `numpy`

```
s = df.col1.str.split(expand=True).stack()
a = s.values[:, None] == [words]

pd.Series(np.where(a.any(1), a.argmax(1), np.nan), s.index).groupby(level=0).min()

0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: your 3rd solution is esp. very thoughtful.